# Edit : How to zoom in and zoom out Content in Hbox draggable node in javafx

Tags: javafx

> Situation :
>   i have HBox with Labels and while click on it should be look like zoom in and zoom out.
>   Consider following String of Labels

ATATATATATATATATA.....50 char
when i zoom it shows me 25 char with some zoomable view how i can get result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold String of labels inside HBOx then Simply on Every click you increase width of label 
create map with labels width and click

on each click maintain flag and set width to label .

label.setWidth(value);
revalidate container.

That It.  hope it will work